# Error: Failed to allocate required memory with OV5640 camera in GStreamer pipeline in Yocto

Tags: camera, linux-device-driver, yocto, gstreamer-1.0, bufferpool

I'm encountering an error while trying to use an OV5640 camera with GStreamer. The error seems to be related to memory allocation.

What could be causing the "Failed to allocate required memory" error in the GStreamer pipeline with the OV5640 camera? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

This is my whole ERROR msg:

```
0:00:01.000589819 162808 0xaaaac424cc00 INFO              GST_STATES gstbin.c:2955:gst_bin_change_state_func:<pipeline0> child 'v4l2src0' changed state to 4(PLAYING) successfully
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:01.003297803 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 ERROR                v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:475:gst_v4l2src_get_input_size_info:<v4l2src0> Cropcap fail, CROPCAP has not supported
0:00:01.004017340 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:820:gst_event_new_caps: creating caps event video/x-raw, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, framerate=(fraction)120/1, format=(string)YUY2, colorimetry=(string)1:4:7:1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:01.007502702 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1317:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<videoconvert0> reuse caps
0:00:01.008158637 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:820:gst_event_new_caps: creating caps event video/x-raw, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, framerate=(fraction)120/1, format=(string)YUY2, colorimetry=(string)1:4:7:1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:01.009526909 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2990:gst_v4l2_object_setup_pool:<v4l2src0:src> accessing buffers via mode 4
0:00:01.010253047 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:567:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> increasing minimum buffers to 2
0:00:01.010323128 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:574:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> increasing minimum buffers to 4
0:00:01.010361289 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:580:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> reducing maximum buffers to 32
0:00:01.010532053 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4532:gst_v4l2_object_decide_allocation:<v4l2src0> Number of buffer allocated 6
0:00:01.010628415 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:580:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> reducing maximum buffers to 32
0:00:01.376023465 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:689:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_streamon:<v4l2src0:pool:src> error with STREAMON 32 (Broken pipe)
0:00:01.376098587 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 ERROR             bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:559:gst_buffer_pool_set_active:<v4l2src0:pool:src> start failed
0:00:01.376145148 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:792:gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation:<v4l2src0> error: Failed to allocate required memory.
0:00:01.376169869 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:792:gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation:<v4l2src0> error: Buffer pool activation failed
0:00:01.376219910 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2154:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<v4l2src0> posting message: Failed to allocate required memory.
0:00:01.376362353 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2181:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<v4l2src0> posted error message: Failed to allocate required memory.
0:00:01.376398474 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3292:gst_base_src_prepare_allocation:<v4l2src0> Subclass failed to decide allocation
0:00:01.376462676 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:01.376487516 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:01.376539117 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2154:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<v4l2src0> posting message: Internal data stream error.
0:00:01.376597679 162808 0xaaaac42e3630 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2181:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<v4l2src0> posted error message: Internal data stream error.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate required memory.
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

I've been experimenting with an OV5640 camera in a GStreamer pipeline, but I keep running into the "Failed to allocate required memory" error. I've tried various elements in the pipeline and even looked into the GStreamer source files related to the error, but I'm still stuck.

Could someone offer guidance on what might be causing this issue and how I can address it?

Comment: We will need more information, like the device you are using (the SoC, its memory), it could be related to the DMA memory pool defined in the device tree. You are already allocating 6 (buffers) * 3840 * 2160 * 2 (YUY2) = ~ 95MB, it can go to 32 buffers (~506MB)

Comment: Hello there,
we are using RZG2M micro-processor and our memory is :
Mem:      total:3851904            used:1046216            free:1039384      shared:100912        buff/cache:1766304      available:2516704
Swap:             0           0           0

Comment: looking at OV5640 datasheet , it only supports max res of 2592x1944 at 15fps, why are you trying to set it to 4k at 120fps?  https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/LightImaging/OV5640_datasheet.pdf

Comment: We've attempted various resolution settings, all of which were handled automatically by GStreamer itself, rather than being manually configured by us.

Comment: We also attempted manual resolution adjustments, yet encountered the same error.